# Carro de compras en web

Tags: php, html, css

buenas noches, tengo un problema y espero que puedan ayudarme, soy diseñador web con poca experiencia y me ofrecieron un trabajo, pero es de tienda virtual y me falta el carrito de compras.

¿Como podría hacer para poder tener el carrito de compras en la pagina virtual que estoy diseñando?

Comment: Hola @hernandez.o, tu pregunta es muy genérica y por ende, tiene un rango de posibles respuestas muy grande. Las preguntas que se responden aquí son en cosas especìficas a las cuales se les puede dar una respuesta concreta. Investiga en la red cómo implementar un carro de compras y, cuando tengas un problema en cierto proceso, puedes publicarla.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sino sabés mucho de programación va a ser bastante complejo implementarlo. Te recomiendo que uses un servicio como **Tienda Nube**, no es caro y se lo podés cobrar a tu cliente como un extra.

Comment: Ok amigo, muchas gracias, me pondré haber eso ahorita mismo, porque necesito eso para terminar la pagina.